# Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete TypeArgument

Tags: java, hashmap

I would like to know why `Dimensions` are required when using the following code:

```
Map<char, int> mapacontador = new HashMap <char, int> ();
```

The error message I get is:

> :Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete TypeArgument.

Comment: char and int are primitives, whereas HashMap takes object types. Try using Character and Integer instead.

Comment: The map should be declared and initialized like this: `Map<Character, Integer> mapaContador = new HashMap<>();` - using object types instead of primitives and diamond operator `<>` existing since Java 7 to infer types and thus reduce verbosity in the assignments.